# Create from scaffolded controller not able to create data in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I used add a new scaffold item in an ASP.NET MVC web app and the create function in the controller is not working for creating item in the database. There is no error on the create page also.

Below is the `FacilitiesController` code.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Status,Capacity,OpenedTime,ClosedTime,ServiceID")] Facility facility)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(facility);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        ViewData["ServiceID"] = new SelectList(_context.Service, "Id", "Id", facility.ServiceID);

        return View(facility);
}
```

I got two models. `Service` Model and `Facility` Model with one to many relationships.

```
public enum PricingType
{
    Item,
    Session,
    Hour,
    Day,
    Week,
    Month
}

public partial class Service
{
    public Service()
    {
        this.Facilities = new HashSet<Facility>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public PricingType PricingType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }
}

public enum FacilityStatus
{
    Available,
    Reserved,
    Occupied,
    Cleaning,
    Maintenance,
    Unknown
} 

public class Facility
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; } 
    public FacilityStatus? Status { get; set; }
    public int? Capacity { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Opened Time")]
    [Range(0.0, 24.0)]
    public double? OpenedTime { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Closed Time")]
    [Range(0.0, 24.0)]
    public double? ClosedTime { get; set; }
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    public Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

After that I `add-migration AddedFacility` like this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Service",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                Price = table.Column<double>(type: "float", nullable: false),
                PricingType = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Service", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Facility",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Status = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                Capacity = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                OpenedTime = table.Column<double>(type: "float", nullable: true),
                ClosedTime = table.Column<double>(type: "float", nullable: true),
                ServiceID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Facility", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Facility_Service_ServiceID",
                    column: x => x.ServiceID,
                    principalTable: "Service",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Facility_ServiceID",
            table: "Facility",
            column: "ServiceID");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Facility");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Service");
    }
```

I can create new `Service` items but when I create new `Facility` item, I was sent back to the create page with no error.

The console is showing this error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (43ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[Name], [s].[Price], [s].[PricingType]
> FROM [Service] AS [s]
> The thread 0x1720 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure: Information: Entity Framework Core 6.0.9 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.9' with options: None
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> SELECT [s].[Id], [s].[Name], [s].[Price], [s].[PricingType]
> FROM [Service] AS [s]
> The thread 0x3680 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The thread 0x33c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The thread 0x4734 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The thread 0x4b94 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The thread 0x3220 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The `Views/Facilities/Create.cshtml` is as below.

```
@model HRMS.Models.Facility

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Facility</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Status" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Status" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<FacilityStatus>()"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Status" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Capacity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Capacity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Capacity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OpenedTime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="OpenedTime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="OpenedTime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ClosedTime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ClosedTime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ClosedTime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ServiceID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ServiceID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ServiceID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I cannot add data is the model state is not valid. So in the model file I have added ? optional to the Service as below. There is an ServiceId in the post data but Service object is not included and may be that is why I cannot add the data.

```
public class Facility
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; } 
    public FacilityStatus? Status { get; set; }
    public int? Capacity { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Opened Time")]
    [Range(0.0, 24.0)]
    public double? OpenedTime { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Closed Time")]
    [Range(0.0, 24.0)]
    public double? ClosedTime { get; set; }
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    public Service? Service { get; set; }
}
```